# Se pueden usar más de un constructor para un mismo form?

Tags: c#

Hola amigos ayer ya pregunte como hace un constructor y fue todo genial la gente se volcó y me hecho el cable que necesitaba, pero ahora tengo otra duda y mi pregunta es la siguiente: 
¿Se puede crear dos constructores de un mismo form? Es que lo estoy intentando de varias formas y el constructor del **"formulario3"** si que funciona pero el constructor **"Variable"** que pasa la variable ID no consigo que funciones, si elimino el constructor **formulario3** si que funciona el constructor **Variable**, pero al estar juntos no. Por aquí os dejo mi código a ver que veis. Gracias de ante mano!

**Forml**

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        int contador = 0;

        int ID = int.Parse(InputBox("Escriba la ID del usuario a editar."));

        DataRow EditID;

        for (int i = 0; i <= maxRegistrosO - 1; i++)
        {
            EditID = dataSet2.Tables["Operarias"].Rows[i];

            if ((int)EditID["id"] == ID)
            {
                contador++;

                EditarOperaria formulario3 = new EditarOperaria(this);
                EditarOperaria VaribaleID = new EditarOperaria(i.ToString());
                formulario3.ShowDialog();
                VaribaleID.ShowDialog();
                this.Show();





            }

        }
```

**Form2**

```
 public partial class EditarOperaria : Form
{
    Form2 fomularioAActualizar2;
    public EditarOperaria(Form2 formulario3)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        fomularioAActualizar2 = formulario3;
    }


    //ID
    private string valorEnForm2;
    public EditarOperaria(string valor)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.valorEnForm2 = valor;
    }

    //conexion a la base de datos
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conexion;
    DataSet dataSet5;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter5;


    // Cantidad de registros en la tabla.
    private int maxRegistros;
    // posicion del registro.
    private int pos;
    //Mostrar usuario
    private void mostrarRegistro()
    {
        DataRow dRegistro = dataSet5.Tables["Operarias"].Rows[int.Parse(valorEnForm2)];


        textBoxENO.Text = dRegistro[1].ToString();
        textBoxEDNIO.Text = dRegistro[2].ToString();
        //textBoxEFechaNacDO.Text = dRegistro[1].ToString();
        textBoxETelefonoO.Text = dRegistro[4].ToString();
        textBoxETelefono2O.Text = dRegistro[5].ToString();
        textBoxEDireccionO.Text = dRegistro[6].ToString();
        textBoxESSO.Text = dRegistro[7].ToString();
        textBoxECBO.Text = dRegistro[8].ToString();
        //textBoxEFechaAlDO.Text = dRegistro[1].ToString();

    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fomularioAActualizar2.MostrarTablaOperarias();
    }
```

Comment: Claro que se pueden tener varios constructores en una clase, pero deben recibir parámetros distintos. Lo que no termino de ver es a que llamas constructor "variable" y que error te da

Comment: Los constructores por separado funcionan perfectamente pero cuando pongo los dos el que funciona es el formulario 3 el otro me da error de contenido vacio en la linea  DataRow dRegistro = dataSet5.Tables["Operarias"].Rows[int.Parse(valorEnForm2)]; del form1

Comment: No se si termino de entender tu codigo. No veo donde llamas a `mostrarRegistro`. Lo que si veo es que si pulsas el boton de tu formulario "variable", `fomularioAActualizar2` es null (dado que no lo has inicializado en el contructor que recibe un string), por lo que te lanzara una excepcion

Comment: por otro lado, en el codigo que muestras tampoco veo donde cargas datos en  `dataSet5`

Comment: el código esta acortado, para no poner aqui muchas líneas he mostrado solo lo que me da problemas, y repito que por separado todo funciona correctamente incluso formularioAActualizar2 funciona correcto la cosa es como te dije antes que todo el problema lo tengo cuando tengo los dos si quito uno de los dos funciona a la perfección, pero los dos juntos no... Si te fojas un constructor pasa solo el valor "I" y el otro es para realizar una funcion del form 1 des de el form2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que observo es que aplicas logica segun el constructor pero no lo validad al momento de usar ese dato

Defines un unico constructor con los dos datos, pero no olvides el constructor sin parametros ya que esto es necesario para el diseñadore, lo requiere el Visual Studio

algo como esto

```
 public partial class EditarOperaria : Form
{
    private readonly Form2 fomularioAActualizar2 = null;
    private readonly int valorEnForm2 = -1;

    public EditarOperaria()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public EditarOperaria(Form2 formulario3, int valor) : this()
    {
        this.valorEnForm2 = valor;
        this.fomularioAActualizar2 = formulario3;
    }


    private void mostrarRegistro()
    {
        if(valorEnForm2 == -1)
            return;

        DataRow dRegistro = dataSet5.Tables["Operarias"].Rows[valorEnForm2];

        //codigo

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(fomularioAActualizar2 == null)
            return;

        fomularioAActualizar2.MostrarTablaOperarias();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Leandro ante todo muchas gracias me parece que va todo por buen camino pero al realizarlo me dan dos errores 1-Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido Estado suprimido
Error CS7036 No se ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda al parámetro formal requerido 'valor' de 'EditarOperaria.EditarOperaria(Form2, int).

Comment: En el formulario 1 habría que cambiar algo? voy un poco perdido lo siento empeze hace 3 dias con visual

Comment: recuerda que en el ejemplo defini el parametro como int, quizas ese valor que pases desde el form1 debas castearlo a int si es que lo tomas como string

Answer (score 1):

Si se pueden tener 2 constructores en una clase.

El problema aca es otro. Tus dos constructores hacen 2 cosas totalmente diferentes.

El constructor se llama cuando "construis" el objeto, eso es al hacer un new de tu objeto.

Entonces como tus constructores hacen cosas distintas, llamar a uno no va a llamar al otro, y lo mas probable es que tengas errores, porque en uno de los casos va a quedar una variable vacia, y en el otro, otra variable distinta vacia.